# asp.net core mvc custom registration page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a very basic task in my **ASP.NET CORE MVC** application. I have two models **Subscriptions** and **Coupons** and they have one to many relations and by using following model classes and scaffolding I was able to generate a **dropDownList** on coupons create page to select anyone of the subscriptions currently in the database.

I am using Entity Framework for my db and scaffolding as well.

**Model classes**

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MonthlyPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MinMonthlyPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MonthlyDiscount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RegisterViewModel> Registrations { get; set; }
}

public class Coupon
{
    [Required]
    public string CouponCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public bool IsPercentage { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Identifier")]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscription Identifier { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ValidMonths { get; set; }
    public bool IsSponsored { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Length { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }       

}
```

now I want the same drop down on my **Registration** page, I am using the built in registration system of **Individual User accounts** and I just want to include the same drop down I have on coupon page to select "subscription" I want the same one on registration page. how can I do that? **AccountsController** is not getting any **ApplicationDbContext** in its constructor parameter unlike other controllers like "couponsController" so that is why I am having trouble figuring out how to get data from database on registration page.

I know that following code helps to get me the subscription list and get only a specific property from it.

```
 // GET: Coupons/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["SubscriptionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Subscription, "ID", "Identifier");
        return View();
    }
```

I want same sort of stuff on my registration page but dbcontext doesn't exist on AccountsController and I cannot new it up because I don't know what options to provide in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have your DbContext, it should just automatically be injected if you create a constructor similar to your other controllers.

```
private ApplicationDbContext _db;

public AccountsController(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}
```

Then you can access your DbSets through that. If that’s not working then check if you have something similar in ConfigureServices in your Startup class:

```
services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If your other controllers have access to the DbContext something similar to that line should already be there.

Comment: where do I call this new constructor? or should I edit existing constructor of AccountsController which is already taking about 4 parameters?

Comment: You can add it to the parameters of the accounts controller constructor. You don’t have to call the constructor yourself as that should happen automatically. Either that or you can initialise a new ApplicationDbContext in your current constructor. It will still have access to the same data.

Comment: thanks bro, it was obvious thing which I didn't see :)